# How do I upgrade gcc's Clang version in OS X?

Tags: macos, gcc, clang

I know that recent Mac OS X versions don't use gcc (g++). When I type gcc or g++ the OS actually uses Clang (cc).

Now, I'm running OS X 10.8.2 with LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28), installed through XCode:

```
$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.28) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

However, buried in the file system there's another more recent Clang version:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
Thread model: posix
```

How can I force gcc to "link" Clang 503... instead of Clang 425...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Xcode, which will give you the latest available versions of both:

```
xcode-select --install
...

$ g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Comment: It seems that the `--install` parameter is missing here: `xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.`. I'm using xcode-select version 2311.

Comment: I guess you may instead need to (re)install Xcode from the Mac App Store https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12